# Redirecting to a page in C# Aspnet MVC after a successful Ajax Post request

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make a redirect to URL after making an Ajax Post request but my code is not redirecting

Here is my sample code.

window.onload = function () {
let base_url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + ":" + window.location.port + "/"; // creating a base url
let URL = base_url+"api/Teacherdata/AddTeacher"; //creating a path
let form = document.forms.new_teacher;

```
form.onsubmit = processForm;

function processForm() {
    let fname = form.teacherfname;
    let lname = form.teacherlname;
    let salary = form.salary;
    let hiredate = form.hiredate;
    let employeenumber = form.employeenumber;

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        
    xhttp.open("POST", URL, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("teacherfname=" + fname.value + "&teacherlname=" + lname.value + "&teacheremployeenumber=" + employeenumber.value + "&teachersalary=" + salary.value + "&teacherhiredate=" + hiredate.value);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            window.location.href = base_url + "teacher/list";
        }
    };
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for redirecting to mvc action method you can use

```
window.location.href = "/{controller}/{action}/{params}";
```

alternatively if you are writing your script in cshtml you can also use

```
 window.location.href = '@Url.Content("~/{controller}/{action}/{params}")';
```